# How to find out what was selected when the paste event fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario**: The user highlights some text in a text box then pastes over the selection. The paste event fires.

In order to handle this correctly in my custom paste handler, I need to know what was highlighted when the paste happened.

It appears though (at least in Firefox), that the browser un-selects the user's selection and then calls the paste handler, which means I can't figure out what was selected by using `window.getSelection`/`document.selection.createRange()`. These are empty at the time the paste event runs, even though text was selected to be overridden.

Is there a way to get the text that would be overridden by paste (because it is selected) if the paste event had not been intercepted?

Comment: Save selection position when selecting text, not when pasting.

Comment: The `onselect` event also has no selection as reported by `window.getSelection`/`document.selection.createRange()`. It seems this event fires before the selection registers, perhaps to allow the selection to be canceled.

Comment: There is a `onselectionchange` event that seems like it would work, but it is new and unsupported. It's scheduled for release in Firefox 52 in March.

Comment: It could be for security reasons, I certainly wouldn't want anyone to know what I pasted in a password field.

Comment: Actually, it looks like a Firefox bug that was reported in 2001... and still not fixed 16 years later. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should be able to get the selected text inside a paste event with `window.getSelection()`, but can't due to a [bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85686) that they still haven't fixed after 16 years!

The workaround is to use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` like:

```
var SelStart = Field.selectionStart;
var SelEnd = Field.selectionEnd;
var SelectedText = Field.value.substring(SelStart,SelEnd);
```